# Reading scores from txt and displaying highest score and records of it

Tags: python

*Starting Out with Python* chapter 6 exercise:

4. High Score
   Assume that a file named scores.txt exists on the computer’s disk. It contains a series of records, each with two fields – a name, followed by a score (an integer between 1 and 100). Write a program that displays the name and score of the record with the highest score, as well as the number of records in the file. (Hint: Use a variable and an “if” statement to keep track of the highest score found as you read through the records, and a variable to keep count of the number of records.)

```
Data in grades.txt
Jennifer 89
Pearson 90
Nancy 95
Gina 100
Harvey 98
Mike 99
Ross 15
Test 90
```

---

```
file=open('grades.txt','r')
my_list=[]

num_of_records=0
highest_score=1
highest_score_name=''

for line in file:
    name,score=line.strip().split()
    if int(score)>highest_score:
        highest_score=int(score)
        highest_score_name=name

    num_of_records=num_of_records+1


print('the name and score of the record with highest score:')
print('Name:',highest_score_name)
print('Score:',highest_score)

print('\nNumber of records:',num_of_records)

file.close()
```

Total starter with python here and trying to get through the book
however hitting error with this question.

Error:

```
line 9, in <module> name,score=line.strip().split() 
  ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Any guides is appreciated.

Comment: What error are you finding, what have you tried to fix the error so far, what are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to display the highest score in the "grades.txt" and keep a record of it

Comment: line 9, in <module>
    name,score=line.strip().split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: hit this error.

Comment: Please update the question with this information.

Comment: hi there, noted and added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### OK got it, what is happening is actually your data has a newline character at the end of file, and when you are trying to split that it results in error. Here is the correct code:

```
file = open('grades.txt', 'r')

num_of_records = 0
highest_score = 1
highest_score_name = ''

for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    # Check whether the line is empty
    if line == '':
        continue

    name, score = line.split()
    if int(score) > highest_score:
        highest_score = int(score)
        highest_score_name = name

    num_of_records = num_of_records+1


print('the name and score of the record with highest score:')
print('Name:', highest_score_name)
print('Score:', highest_score)

print('\nNumber of records:', num_of_records)

file.close()
```

**Hope it helps you:)**

Comment: name,score=line.strip().split(", ")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Can you please show me the data contained in grades.txt

Comment: hi there, i have updated the data in the question above.

Comment: According to data you have posted there shouldn't be any error, but let me check one more time.

Comment: hey there, it works perfectly now! thank you so much shubham! thanks for taking the time to help me go through this!

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you hit this error:

```
line 9, in <module> name,score=line.strip().split() ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

This indicates a problem in one line of the file. I assume there's an empty line in your file. You could either check for that before unpacking the value or do an error handling with `try`/`except`. As you're quite early in, I think checking if the line contains anything is on par with the learning progress:

```
if line.strip():
    name,score=line.split()
```

This way you're only unpacking the line if the variable isn't empty after removing whitespaces.

Comment: hi there isn't an empty space inside my grades.txt
if line.strip():
    name,score=line.split()
i tried this and hit this error
line 9, in <module>
    name,score=line.split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)